# Execute command from js file for creating sails app

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, sails.js

I have the following test.js file.

test.js

```
 var assert = require('assert');
 var path= require('path');

 exec('pwd')                                    //Display current Dir
 exec('sails new App')                          //Create New Sails App
 exec('cd App')                                 //Change to App Directory
 exec('sails new generate model alpha')         //Generate Model
 exec('sails new generate controller alpha')    //Generate Controller

 describe('Test controller created or not ', function(){
    it('Equal with Controller Directory Path', function(done){
        assert.equal(path.resolve('api/controller/','Alphacontroller') , path.resolve('api/controller/','Alphacontroller'));
done();
   });
 });
```

So that if

`Run  $ Mocha test.js` 
Should create App , generate model , controller and check whether Controller created or not

I am Using Mocha as my test framework.

Comment: As @bredikhin notes below, the generators are tested in the framework.  Also, `sails new generate model alpha` is not going to do what you expect--it'll create a new app called "generate".  To generate a model is just `sails generate model [modelName]`; for controller it's `sails generate controller [controllerName]`

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you need to test the generators, which is a framework code that's supposed to be already tested?

Anyways, you can test `sails new app` with something like this:

```
it('should create a new application', function(done) {
  exec('sails new ' + appName, function(err) {
    if (err)
      return done(new Error(err));

    assert(something, isRight); // You can verify the files generated or whatnot
    done();
  });
});
```

Similarly with model / controller generation. Basically, you had the right approach, it's just important to remember about callbacks.